# Performance difference between using IIS Static Content Serving Vs Fetching data from SQL Server Jquery WCF

Tags: jquery, performance, sql-server-2008, static, iis-7.5

We have a portal developed in ASP .Net hosted in Windows 2008 IIS server accessed globally (extra-net) by over 200,000 people out of which 40% of them concurrent.

1. part of the portal, we will need to show notifications specific to the user

   (there could be 50+ notifications daily, which will contain say 20 lines of presented content shown through HTML)
2. portal should also have capability to search those notifications specific to the user.
3. notifications can be received at the server as XML files.(either real time or scheduled way)
4. we want to build this piece of architecture highly performant
5. Let me know which one of the subject will meet the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ah this reminds me of something I did in my previous startup Pageflakes. We had to push alerts, notifications to individual users and allow each user to mark them as read.

First, we thought of doing it the usual way. create a Notification table having a userID and the notification title and read flag. But that gets heavily fragmented over time and gets slower and slower and indexes need to be rebuilt etc as millions of notifications get added/updated/deleted.

So, we chose alternative. We added a Notification table which has a UserID, but it has a giant char column that holds an XML that has all the notifications user can see. Since you never need to search across users, one user will always look at the notifications of that user only. This means the Notification table can at worst have the same number of rows as the user table, never more. And we aren't adding/updating/deleting rows on this table frequently, thus no DB framentation, index rebuild etc issues.

You can try the same. Create a Notification table that has:

```
Notification:
=============
UserID int FK to user table
RecentNotifications  char(4000)
ArchivedNotifications char(4000)
```

On the RecentNotifications, you store the XML that has the notifications that needs to be shown to user. The ArchiveNotifications contains the archived messages that user can see when user goes to some Notification page.

You can use some xml to store it:

```
<notifications>
  <notification title="" datetime="" read="yes/no" />
</notifications>
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This speaks about only the DB store approach, let me know how this is better than Static content approach, where notification content is stored as separate HTML files, and it is downloaded to browser once after which it need not download (for a content expiration duration), Also i am not sure how 4000 characters are enough in the long run (i mentioned about 50/day/user)

Comment: to give you the latest buzz from Stackoverflow architecture itself. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/the-speed-of-light-sucks/ :)

Comment: If you use static html content, then it if gets cached on browser, user is not receiving notifications until browser downloads the latest notification html. It's always best to store it in database and emit it as part of the page output. Storing important data as notification, which gets cached, means user will see outdated notification.

Comment: Moreover, user might click some notification as "Read". That should go away from the page. But if you use html, which is cached, as soon as the page is reloaded, the notification comes back again as if it wasn't read because browser is showing you content from a cached html, which is out dated.

Comment: I have used 4000 characters to ensure the table can still be index rebuilt online. If I use varchar(max), you can't to index rebuild. Thus overtime the table gets slower and slower and you have to take a downtime to bring the table back to its original performance.

Comment: For older notifications, you can move them to some archive table. Since such tables aren't high read, you can use varchar(max) there because archive tables always grow. Moreover, you can do offline index build because not many users are looking at the archived notification table.

Comment: //user is not receiving notifications until browser downloads the latest notification html// well this logic of looking latest can't be built in a Jquery efficiently?  (also you assumed the notification should go away, my case it will reside in the list but not in a "BOLD" just ordinary font. Let me know my assumptions explained to you clearly.

Comment: You can use jQuery to hit a unique url on the html every time. Say www.site.com/user/a/notification.html?123123123123. This way you can avoid the cache. But then again, why do this? You need to generate html files on the webserver. that means only one webserver. You can't use load balanced environment. Without LB, you can't scale. You can use network share from multiple webservers, but that's slow and non-scalable. There are so many problems with static html file generation. Database with some good caching logic is the way to go.

Comment: //This way you can avoid the cache// Am not sure i clearly understood this line, because the idea of using static is once the piece of html dowloaded it need not download again. (this include the JS, Images associated too),//You can't use load balanced environment//, why if we have massively parallel processing (using .net 4.0 parallel stuff.) why not we save the same files in multiple servers. //You can use network share from multiple webservers//,how about using FusionIO kind of in memory to get the performance?, also do note that files once downloaded willnt be looked again,saves processing